# How to set a charset header for a html page?

Tags: html, character-encoding, content-type, meta-tags

Even though i use the below meta tag to set the content-type and charset, i am not seeing the charset header in the firefox firebug debugger.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Any help is appericiated.

Comment: By the way, it's better not to use the ISO-8859-1 charset in this day and age. It is tainted. If you use it, you don't actually trigger the real ISO-8859-1 codepage anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The `meta` tag does not affect the HTTP headers sent. (Long ago, it was kind-of meant to do such things, but apart some forgotten experiments, it never did.) It specifies the encoding to be implied *if* HTTP headers do not specify the encoding; so it’s really not equivalent to an HTTP header (as the name ´http-equiv` suggests) but a replacement, surrogate, Ersatz for an HTTP header.

The way to set the HTTP headers depends on the server software and its settings.

But if the headers do not specify the encoding, then the `meta` tag takes effect. You ca check via the View → Encoding menu in Firefox which encoding is being applied.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

It is how you set charset header for HTML files,there is nothing wrong.

Why would you use firebug to check the Charset? Just right click your mouse key and from the context menu select `view page info` and it will give you the page charset.